# In Firefox, jump to the correct line in a minified stylesheet

Tags: css, firefox, stylesheet, gecko, inspect

In Firefox, if I am inspecting a page's HTML, and I click on one of the styles that applies to the element I am viewing, then it jumps to the page's stylesheet and to the correct line.

But if the CSS is minified, then in the Inspector sidebar, it gives the line as line 1 since the stylesheet is minified. But when I click on the link, it goes to an expanded version of the stylesheet. However, I am not jumped to the correct line; instead, I remain at line 1.

Is there a way to make Firefox jump me to the correct stylesheet line, even when it is minified? It clearly knows how to expand a minified stylesheet, but it doesn't seem to know how to jump to the correct line after expanding the minified stylesheet.